# Android Studio Files Messed Up After An Update

Tags: android, android-studio

Today, most of my files at an Android Studio project messed up after an Android Studio update (Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2). Here's how it looks.

[image]

I've tried everything, clean project, rebuild project, invalidate caches and restart, even deleting files in .grade, and .idea, and other several folders in project and C://user/ directory.

Fortunately if I open any of the files in explorer, it's still good, not messed up. But if it opened Android Studio, it will get messed up no matter what I do.

Is there anything else I can do to revert these files back so I can code again in Android Studio?

Comment: I got same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294088/android-studio-project-getting-corrupted-after-a-restart

Answer (score 0):

Create a brand new project from scratch and copy your source files into that!