# android studio projects getting corrupted after a restart

Tags: android, android-studio

After upgrading to arctic fox, I faced this issue. Opened a project I worked previously with older version of android studio was fine, but after restart its files became full with gibberish values. I thought its a hardware failure issue. But this happening again today with other projects, so I want a solution.

After working, closing and reopening the project the files contents became corrupted/changed:

[image]

File contents changed on previous project, showing difference with git:

[image]

ArcticFoxPatch2, Projects are built with gradle 7.0.2.

Solutions tried:

1. I have tried potential solution of invalidating cache and restart, but the files stays same.
2. Android studio warns and suggest wrong encoding but reloading with multiple other encoding did not resolve file contents.

What should be a solution?
Should I change hardware, eg ssd? or downgrade android studio?

Comment: check code in this from the folder structure...go to your project location and check the files...if they have the required code...then uninstall android studio...delete every related files and folders (not the project obviously) and then reinstall the android studio...this should solve the issue..

Answer (score -1):

Please run android studio like this.
Click Android Studio and click right button on mouse, then click "Run as Administrator".

Hope it helpful for you.

Comment: Ask google for arctic fox. I got same error in the last month.

Comment: Unfortunately giving administrative privilage did not resolve the issue.